# localhost/foldername not working after upgrading to Yosemite

Tags: apache-http-server, localhost, osx-yosemite

After upgrading to Yosemite I can no longer access folders in my `Sites` directory like this:

`http://localhost/foldername`

instead I have to add `~myusername` after `localhost` like this:

`http://localhost/~username/foldername`

or I'm getting the following error:

```
Not Found

The requested URL /foldername was not found on this server.
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

In case anyone has the same problem, this is the solution:

> in your httpd.conf file ... search for "DocumentRoot" ... then change
>   that entry and the  entry to read "/Users/< your username
>   goes here >/Sites" then sudo apachectl restart ... this should then
>   load the pages w/o needing the ~/username part (at least it worked for
>   me)

more info: http://coolestguidesontheplanet.com/get-apache-mysql-php-phpmyadmin-working-osx-10-10-yosemite/ (see comments below)

Answer (score 0):

I just restarted Apache (sudo apachectl restart) and it worked fine but you should follow Levani's advice and check your DocumentRoot Settings.

Answer (score 0):

I just downloaded phpMyAdmin from [here](http://www.phpmyadmin.net/home_page/index.php) and copy the folder to your Sites folder. In my case is /Library/WebServer/Documents/